# IBAction triggered twice when tapping quickly

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a weird problem. I have a view that's used to set user settings. I have it in a regular menu for common access and when I tap the UIButtons within this scene they execute the IBAction callback only once. Even when you spam the button. Which is a good thing.

Now, for making things faster for the user I also allow access to this same ViewController elsewhere. This time instead of using a push animation I instantiate the ViewController on my own and show it on top of everything else. For some reason in this context if I tap buttons quickly the IBAction is called multiple times.

This is a problem for me because I have a performSegue within the IBAction and it pushes the next view twice. So when the user returns it returns to the same View and if you return one more time it crashes the app.

I don't know how to solve this problem because the same UIViewController is behaving differently in two different contexts...

I'm using xcode 4.5

Comment: I've had issues like this in the past where I accidentally wired up connections multiple times in Interface Builder to that button. May want to take a quick peak and see how many connections are wired up in the connections tab of the attribute inspector in IB.. Maybe......

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. Wouldn't that trigger it twice when you press it once too?

Comment: So when you instantiate this yourself, are you putting it inside a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on your IBAction and see/confirm that there's an exact same call stack with both invocations?